# Magento find out from which csv file are the translations loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, localisation, transactional-mail, email-translation

I have Magento-1.9.2.4 ce installed in one of my client's site along with module [Scommerce CashBack](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cash-back-discount.html).

Now when I place an order which has cashback amount applied to it, I want to translate the label `Discount (%s)` to `Discount124 (%s)` in the Transactional Email generated for New Order. I am able to do translation for Discount in Order review in frontend and also in Cart page, but the same translation doesn't work in transactional email. What could be the reason for this ?

Moreover, how to put a debug line (also, what line should I put ?) to find out when label "Discount" is found in email template by `mailer` object, it's translation is done by exactly which csv file ?

I tried some debugging in overrided `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php` after line 401 as per below:

```
if (stripos(strtolower($text), 'Discount') !== false) {
                $translationData[] = array('code' => $code, 'module' => $module, 'text' => $text, 'translated' => $translated);
                echo "<pre/>";print_r($translationData);
}
```

But even this throws me off instead of giving me the exact csv file from where the word 'Discount' is translated, how to find it as it is very crucial for me.

Comment: Check out my answer in the linked duplicate. I have an extension that gives you this information: https://github.com/schmengler/TranslationHints

Answer (score 0):

checkout the app/design/ frontend/namespace/yourtheme/locale

OR
app/design/frontend/base/default/locale

Comment: Already did that but no luck with it so far. Also I want to find a key to getting the translation cs responsible for specific word translation, once and for all.